# Creating an array of files in a subfolder

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I'm trying to write a bash script for a homework question where I need to access some files in a source folder, remove all comments from them and send the uncommented files (or a copy) to a destination folder, here's my current attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash
destination="$1"
source="$2"
mkdir "$destination"
files=(${$("$source"/*)})
for file in "${files[@]}" 
do  
    grep -E -v "^[[:space:]]*[//]" "$file">> "/$destination/$file"
done
```

The problem seems to be I'm not creating the array elements correctly, I want the array to contain the names of the files in the source folder, can anyone direct me to the correct way of doing that (preferably without solving the whole exercise as it is homework after all)/

Answer (score 4):

Change this

```
files=(${$("$source"/*)})
```

to

```
files=("$source"/*) # grab name of all files under $source dir and store it in array
```

Comment: unfortunately both this solution and the below one return the string source/file_1 while I need the string file_1

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't need the array at all, and for a large number of matching files it is more efficient as well to iterate over the pattern directly.

```
for file in "$source"/*; do
```